# Combining Multiple jQuery Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting, ssi

I'm trying to create a simple portfolio site for a friend of mine based around his drawings and paintings. The layout is relatively simple but is proving to be very difficult to implement. I have three jquery scripts on the page that each perform a specific function.

1) bgStretcher - Stretches a series of background images to fill a user's window.

2) collapse - Simple collapsable menu system

3) galleryview - Basic no frills slideshow gallery

Currently, bgstretcher and collapse are on one page called nav.shtml (http://yungchoi.com/nav.shtml) and the gallery on gallery.shtml(http://yungchoi.com/gallery.shtml). Seperatley they work fine, but when I call the nav page via SSI ([test.shtml](http://yungchoi.com/test.shtml)), The code seems to run into problems and becomes disabled.

The solutions I've found all lead to utilizing the noConflict function in jquery (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656360/use-multiple-jquery-and-jquery-ui-libraries), (http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-use-jQuery_noConflict), but everytime I've tried inserting it and changing my code, everything gets messed up again. I've also organized each script's files into separate folders and directories but that hasn't helped either.

My experience is in graphic and web design, so my coding skills are not the greatest. I do know the basics, but rewriting jquery code was not something I ever learned so I might not be understanding how to correctly fix this problem. If someone could clearly and easily explain what I would need to do to make these all work together, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have multiple versions of jQuery being loaded in your page.

Remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="support/bgstrecher/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="support/collapse/jquery-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you should also remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

& - (because you only need either the packed or unpacked version, not both)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="galleryview/jquery.galleryview-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

See if that helps.

You only need noConflict if you're going to also use other libraries that are similar to jQuery like MooTools, Dojo or Prototype. It's unlikely you will need to & if you do, you will need to recode to use the jQuery function instead of the $.

The issue it appears you're having is that all these jQuery includes are overwriting the previous version of jQuery which the plugin attached to and thus the function no longer exists when you call it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've deleted what you recommended, the page at http://yungchoi.com/nav.shtml now loads the gallery but not any of the images. Also since jquery is only being called on that page, if I call nav.shtml on any new page that doesn't have include a gallery, the scripts won't work anymore.

Comment: nav.shtml is not working because you've excluded jquery-1.3.2.min.js without replacing it with <script type="text/javascript" src="galleryview/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> . You must load at least one version of jQuery. All the plugins you're using include outdated copies of jQuery. Make sure all your pages only reference one version of jQuery, the lastest version you have available to you locally is the one included with the galleryview plugin.

Comment: As for the galleryview not showing up, try adding : #gallery { z-index:2} under one of your <style type='text/css'> tags.

Comment: Klinky, I appreciate all the help. The nav now works just as you suggested. But after trying out what you said, I'm still not able to see galleryview. I've added #gallery to the css and still nothing. Any ideas? It would definitely help me out.

Comment: Delete <script type="text/javascript" src="galleryview/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> on Line 60, you already have this line earlier in the page on Line 8. If you're working with multiple plugins, do not copy the examples given in their documentation directly because you must only load jQuery once. Make sure you don't copy any lines of code that would reload jQuery again.

Comment: YES!! Thank you, I finally got it working. You have no idea how much I appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading Jquery twice ?

First the 1.4.2 min file and then the full blown straight after ?

Comment: I didn't realize that was happening, but I just removed it. Still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

You still have multiple calls to jQuery (even if files are not in same directories).
In the same way, you call "galleryview/jquery.galleryview-2.1.1.js" twice (the second file is just packed).

By the way, my error console tell me that:

"Error: jQuery.timer is undefined
Source File: http://yungchoi.com/galleryview/jquery.timers-1.2.js
Line: 135"

Are you sure you need this timer plugin? For now, it seems you have too many script included. Try to remove all unneeded files (you should keep only one version of jquery. But if some plugins you used is not compatible with, you'll have more and more compatibility problems).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Most of what was wrong are now fixed.