# jquery.js is conflicting with js of my theme 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

I am very new to JavaScript.

In my website I use `1.8.3.min.js` and everything is working fine.

For the UI I used `1.10.1.custom.min.js`.

But when I put jquery.js in that all functionality of theme is stopped due to that and some of my code will not work without `jquery.js`.

How can I do this?

Error is here when I remove that js then again it will display in other js error

TypeError: e.isPlainObject is not a function

```
...e-hover"),e(this).addClass("ui-state-hover"),this.className.indexOf("ui-datepick...

jquery....min.js (line 6)
TypeError: a(...).on is not a function


...a(this),f=e.data("bs.modal"),g=a.extend({},b.DEFAULTS,e.data(),"object"==typeof ...

bootstrap.min.js (line 9)
```

Here is my all js

```
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


           <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>js/template.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>js/user.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-ricksaw-chart/js/d3.v2.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-ricksaw-chart/js/rickshaw.min.js"></script>
        <?php if ($UserInformation['GroupInformation']['PaymentSystem'] == 'Enabled' && $UserInformation['GroupInformation']['CreditSystem'] == 'Enabled'): ?>
        <script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>js/screens/user/credit.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <?php endif; ?>

<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/boostrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/breakpoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE JS FRAMEWORK -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS -->
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-block-ui/jqueryblockui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-slider/jquery.sidr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-numberAnimate/jquery.animateNumbers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/js/tabs_accordian.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/js/email_comman.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!-- BEGIN CORE TEMPLATE JS -->
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/js/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't need multiple jquery libraries, if you do [take a look at this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Multiple jQuery and jQuery UI Libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656360/use-multiple-jquery-and-jquery-ui-libraries)

Comment: both are needed 1.8.3 is needed for my theme my theme is used 1.8.3 and functionality is used jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is remove your include of jQuery 1.8.3.

```
<!-- Remove the following line -->
<script src="<?php InterfaceTemplateURL(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery 1.10.1 is an improvement over 1.8.3, and you're *very* unlikely to be using any of the deprecated functionality between the two. If another part of your page is loading 1.10.1, just use it.

Comment: both are needed 1.8.3 is needed for my theme my theme is used 1.8.3 and functionality is used jquery.js

Comment: @parth: No, both are not needed. You only need to have one version of jQuery loaded on the page, in 99.999999% of situations. This almost certainly is not one of them. Use the most recent one.

Comment: Sir Thank you but i know that one js needed , 1.8.3 is used for main js and 1.10.1 is jquery.ui js that both are working fine but when i attach jquery.js all functionality stopped of 1.8.3

Comment: @parth: Again: You **do not need** multiple versions of jQuery loaded. You've said you're very new to this stuff; I am not (and neither are the other people telling you you don't need multiple versions). Your "main js" will work with 1.10.1, almost certainly. If you stop focusing on the idea you need multiple versions loaded, you'll get to the solution faster.